# Add Class to Input element of ng input tag

Tags: angularjs

I am playing with ng-input-tag and wanted to add bootstrap class to the input element of html so as to get its particular bootstrap class styles, but its not working as expected.
Below is the code:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', ['ngTagsInput'])
  .controller('myCtrl', function() {

  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/3.1.1/ng-tags-input.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/readable/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/3.1.1/ng-tags-input.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/3.1.1/ng-tags-input.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
  
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="disabledInput">Disabled input</label>
  <tags-input ng-model="tags" class="form-control"></tags-input>
</div>

</div>
```

So i hope you ran the code and found that i am unable to get bootstrap form-control class style for  directive.

Here is Plunker link : https://plnkr.co/edit/jZlAsJ?p=info

Comment: @Samsull Arefeen tried adding bootstrap.min.js, still didn't work for me.I wanted only the style of bootstrap not the jquery of bootstrap for this, so didn't add. Will that affect any of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/3.1.1/ng-tags-input.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/3.1.1/ng-tags-input.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/3.1.1/ng-tags-input.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script>
    angular
      .module('myApp', ['ngTagsInput'])
      .controller('myCtrl', function() {

      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="disabledInput"> input</label>
      <tags-input ng-model="tags"></tags-input>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @jtsnr, it worked.But i am using bootstrap for complete application.I do need bootstrap 3 styles for my pages. now i can't remove the bootstrap out.. o.O

Comment: Hi Naren. I've updated my answer by including the bootstrap css and also removing the form-control class from the tags-input. This seems to work okay. Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

See this plunker ... I've solved this for you ( you may need to modify the styling a bit).

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/sKxMOLWoDPtYNqE8hunS?p=preview
```

You need to add jquery in your code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Bootstrap js will need jquery to run. Please keep in mind that you have added jquery (above script) before bootstrap.js (watch my code carefully, review the sequel).